# If $EX^2 < \infty$ and $EY^2 < \infty$, are we guaranteed that $EXY < \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I was wondering under what conditions does $EX^2 < \infty$ and $EY^2 < \infty$, guarantee that $EXY < \infty$? Or is this just false usually?

I tried to come up with some counterexamples, but had little success.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells you more.  $|EXY| \le (EX^2)^{1/2}(EY^2)^{1/2}$.  Note.  For something not known to be positive, it is strange to write $EXY < \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Note the following: For any real numbers $a$ and $b$, the following holds: $|ab| \le a^2+b^2$. This implies the following: At each point $x$, the following string of inequalities hold: $0 \le |X(x)Y(x)| \le X^2(x) + Y^2(x)$.

This implies the following: If both $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ are both finite, then so must $\mathbb{E}[|XY|]$, and therefore $\mathbb{E}[XY]$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$|x-y|^2\ge 0$$
so
$$x^2+y^2\ge 2|xy|$$